# Rail 4: Conditionals in a Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still learning RoR but I cant learn by following someone else's code. I have decided to implement by own app.

I have generated a scaffold and in the `_form.html.erb` I have this:

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :bath_accessories %><br>
 <%= f.select :bath_accessories, options_for_select(["Shower", "Extractor Fan", "Lights", "Shaver", "Heat Rail"]) %><br>
</div>
```

When the user selects "Shower" from the above lists, I want to enable in view:

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :watts %><br>
 <%= f.number_field :watts %>
</div>
```

I am lost where to put the if statement for: `<%= f.select :bath_accessories, options_for_select(["Shower", "Extractor Fan", "Lights", "Shaver", "Heat Rail"]) %>` But I did this and nothing shows:

```
<% if :bath_accessories[0] %>
  # What to out put here with "<%= code %>?
```

Generated HTML Tag:

```
<form class="new_bathroom_accessory" id="new_bathroom_accessory" action="/bathroom_accessories" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="r9M+Q7Np+/i68gwj65JSvV8wi4+4yb5d6tFWBHMw8k9nz1oRHGzh7AZHOTFvlaiS2lmqTch356vVYNlh7Urifw==" />

<div class="field">
 <label for="bathroom_accessory_bath_accessories">Bath accessories</label><br>
<select name="bathroom_accessory[bath_accessories]"   id="bathroom_accessory_bath_accessories"><option value="Shower">Shower</option>
<option value="Extractor Fan">Extractor Fan</option>
<option value="Lights">Lights</option>
<option value="Shaver">Shaver</option>
<option value="Heat Rail">Heat Rail</option></select><br>
</div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="bathroom_accessory_watts">Watts</label><br>
 <input type="number" name="bathroom_accessory[watts]" id="bathroom_accessory_watts" />
</div>
<div class="field">
 <label for="bathroom_accessory_volts">Volts</label><br>
 <input type="number" name="bathroom_accessory[volts]" id="bathroom_accessory_volts" />
</div>

 <div class="actions">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Bathroom accessory" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `<% if :bath_accessories[0] %>` doesn't make any sense, it won't work. What's more, you can't do it in erb, because erb templates are generated server-side, but you need to show additional field upon user action, on client side. So you should use JavaScript, search for showing additional fields after select input change.

Comment: Hi @MarekLipka So anything for client-side will be for JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, if you want to do something dynamically in client-side, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Can you paste the `HTML code` generated for that `select tag`? I can write an answer for you.

Comment: @Pavan Done. Have  a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding an `id` to particular `<div>`,you can control that `<div>` as per user selection.

```
<div class="field" id="shower_id">
 <%= f.label :watts %><br>
 <%= f.number_field :watts %>
</div>
```

And you need `JavaScript` or `JQuery` code like this

```
$('#bathroom_accessory_bath_accessories').on('change',function(){
        if( $(this).val()==="Shower"){
        $("#shower_id").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#shower_id").hide()
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/0t86pqbk/7/)